How to disable mouse snapping to screen edges on KDE under Wayland?
Trying out Wayland after much trouble getting it to be up to par with X11 in terms of used features. But since I switched sessions (and nothing else) I now have the most annoying mouse pointer snapping to screen edges.
Want to drag the scrollbar of a fullscreen window? No, I apparently really should be resizing the window instead. Want to move the mouse from a screen to the next one? How about stopping at the edge instead? Such a tiny issue, but so infuriating.
I find if I move my mouse fast enough the snapping is ignored (really useful to aim for the scrollbar…).
I’ve been rummaging through the options but to no avail. Tried a ton of searching online too, but I can only find people with other jumpy mouse issues – not related to window/screen edges it seems. If my answer exists out there, it’s drowned out in the noise.
So any chance someone knows how to fix this? Or am I better off leaving Wayland mature for another 5 years before I try it again?
I’m running the following:
Operating System: openSUSE Tumbleweed 20240924
KDE Plasma Version: 6.1.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 6.6.0
Qt Version: 6.7.3
Kernel Version: 6.10.11-1-default (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: Wayland


Here's the (likely way too detailed) info dump from Wayland
interface: 'wl_compositor',                              version:  6, name:  1
interface: 'zwp_tablet_manager_v2',                      version:  1, name:  3
interface: 'zwp_keyboard_shortcuts_inhibit_manager_v1',  version:  1, name:  4
interface: 'zxdg_decoration_manager_v1',                 version:  1, name:  5
interface: 'wp_viewporter',                              version:  1, name:  6
interface: 'wp_security_context_manager_v1',             version:  1, name:  7
interface: 'wp_fractional_scale_manager_v1',             version:  1, name:  8
interface: 'wl_shm',                                     version:  1, name:  9
    formats (fourcc):
    0x38344258 = 'XB48'
    0x38344241 = 'AB48'
    0x30334258 = 'XB30'
    0x30334241 = 'AB30'
    0x30335258 = 'XR30'
    0x30335241 = 'AR30'
             1 = 'XR24'
             0 = 'AR24'
interface: 'wl_seat',                                    version:  9, name: 10
    name: 
    capabilities: pointer keyboard touch
    keyboard repeat rate: 25
    keyboard repeat delay: 600
interface: 'zwp_pointer_gestures_v1',                    version:  3, name: 11
interface: 'zwp_pointer_constraints_v1',                 version:  1, name: 12
interface: 'zwp_relative_pointer_manager_v1',            version:  1, name: 13
interface: 'wl_data_device_manager',                     version:  3, name: 14
interface: 'zwlr_data_control_manager_v1',               version:  2, name: 15
interface: 'wp_cursor_shape_manager_v1',                 version:  1, name: 16
interface: 'zwp_primary_selection_device_manager_v1',    version:  1, name: 17
interface: 'org_kde_kwin_idle',                          version:  1, name: 18
interface: 'zwp_idle_inhibit_manager_v1',                version:  1, name: 19
interface: 'ext_idle_notifier_v1',                       version:  1, name: 20
interface: 'org_kde_plasma_shell',                       version:  8, name: 21
interface: 'org_kde_kwin_appmenu_manager',               version:  1, name: 22
interface: 'org_kde_kwin_server_decoration_palette_manager', version:  1, name: 23
interface: 'org_kde_plasma_virtual_desktop_management',  version:  2, name: 25
interface: 'org_kde_kwin_shadow_manager',                version:  2, name: 27
interface: 'org_kde_kwin_dpms_manager',                  version:  1, name: 28
interface: 'org_kde_kwin_server_decoration_manager',     version:  1, name: 29
interface: 'kde_output_management_v2',                   version:  9, name: 30
interface: 'zxdg_output_manager_v1',                     version:  3, name: 31
    xdg_output_v1
        output: 68
        name: 'DP-1'
        logical_x: 0, logical_y: 0
        logical_width: 1080, logical_height: 1920
    xdg_output_v1
        output: 66
        name: 'HDMI-A-1'
        logical_x: 1080, logical_y: 420
        logical_width: 1920, logical_height: 1080
    xdg_output_v1
        output: 61
        name: 'eDP-1'
        logical_x: 3000, logical_y: 840
        logical_width: 1920, logical_height: 1080
interface: 'wl_subcompositor',                           version:  1, name: 32
interface: 'zxdg_exporter_v2',                           version:  1, name: 33
interface: 'zxdg_importer_v2',                           version:  1, name: 34
interface: 'xdg_activation_v1',                          version:  1, name: 37
interface: 'wp_content_type_manager_v1',                 version:  1, name: 39
interface: 'wp_tearing_control_manager_v1',              version:  1, name: 40
interface: 'xdg_toplevel_drag_manager_v1',               version:  1, name: 41
interface: 'kde_screen_edge_manager_v1',                 version:  1, name: 42
interface: 'frog_color_management_factory_v1',           version:  1, name: 43
interface: 'wp_presentation',                            version:  1, name: 44
    presentation clock id: 1 (CLOCK_MONOTONIC)
interface: 'xdg_wm_dialog_v1',                           version:  1, name: 45
interface: 'xdg_wm_base',                                version:  6, name: 48
interface: 'zwlr_layer_shell_v1',                        version:  5, name: 49
interface: 'wp_drm_lease_device_v1',                     version:  1, name: 51
    path: /dev/dri/card1
interface: 'kde_output_order_v1',                        version:  1, name: 52
interface: 'zwp_text_input_manager_v1',                  version:  1, name: 53
interface: 'zwp_text_input_manager_v2',                  version:  1, name: 54
interface: 'zwp_text_input_manager_v3',                  version:  1, name: 55
interface: 'wl_drm',                                     version:  2, name: 57
interface: 'zwp_linux_dmabuf_v1',                        version:  4, name: 58
    main device: 0xE201 (/dev/dri/card1 or /dev/dri/renderD128)
    tranche
        target device: 0xE201 (/dev/dri/card1 or /dev/dri/renderD128)
        flags: none
        formats (fourcc) and modifiers (names):
        0x38344241 = 'AB48'; 0x0000000000000000 = LINEAR
        0x38344241 = 'AB48'; 0x0100000000000001 = INTEL_X_TILED
        0x38344241 = 'AB48'; 0x0100000000000002 = INTEL_Y_TILED
        0x38344241 = 'AB48'; 0x0100000000000006 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS
        0x38344241 = 'AB48'; 0x0100000000000008 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS_CC
        0x38344241 = 'AB48'; 0x00ffffffffffffff = INVALID
        0x38344258 = 'XB48'; 0x0000000000000000 = LINEAR
        0x38344258 = 'XB48'; 0x0100000000000001 = INTEL_X_TILED
        0x38344258 = 'XB48'; 0x0100000000000002 = INTEL_Y_TILED
        0x38344258 = 'XB48'; 0x0100000000000006 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS
        0x38344258 = 'XB48'; 0x0100000000000008 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS_CC
        0x38344258 = 'XB48'; 0x00ffffffffffffff = INVALID
        0x35315241 = 'AR15'; 0x0000000000000000 = LINEAR
        0x35315241 = 'AR15'; 0x0100000000000001 = INTEL_X_TILED
        0x35315241 = 'AR15'; 0x0100000000000002 = INTEL_Y_TILED
        0x35315241 = 'AR15'; 0x0100000000000006 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS
        0x35315241 = 'AR15'; 0x0100000000000008 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS_CC
        0x35315241 = 'AR15'; 0x00ffffffffffffff = INVALID
        0x3231564e = 'NV12'; 0x0000000000000000 = LINEAR
        0x3231564e = 'NV12'; 0x0100000000000001 = INTEL_X_TILED
        0x3231564e = 'NV12'; 0x0100000000000002 = INTEL_Y_TILED
        0x3231564e = 'NV12'; 0x00ffffffffffffff = INVALID
        0x20203852 = 'R8  '; 0x0000000000000000 = LINEAR
        0x20203852 = 'R8  '; 0x0100000000000001 = INTEL_X_TILED
        0x20203852 = 'R8  '; 0x0100000000000002 = INTEL_Y_TILED
        0x20203852 = 'R8  '; 0x0100000000000006 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS
        0x20203852 = 'R8  '; 0x0100000000000008 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS_CC
        0x20203852 = 'R8  '; 0x00ffffffffffffff = INVALID
        0x48344241 = 'AB4H'; 0x0000000000000000 = LINEAR
        0x48344241 = 'AB4H'; 0x0100000000000001 = INTEL_X_TILED
        0x48344241 = 'AB4H'; 0x0100000000000002 = INTEL_Y_TILED
        0x48344241 = 'AB4H'; 0x0100000000000006 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS
        0x48344241 = 'AB4H'; 0x0100000000000008 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS_CC
        0x48344241 = 'AB4H'; 0x00ffffffffffffff = INVALID
        0x20363152 = 'R16 '; 0x0000000000000000 = LINEAR
        0x20363152 = 'R16 '; 0x0100000000000001 = INTEL_X_TILED
        0x20363152 = 'R16 '; 0x0100000000000002 = INTEL_Y_TILED
        0x20363152 = 'R16 '; 0x0100000000000006 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS
        0x20363152 = 'R16 '; 0x0100000000000008 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS_CC
        0x20363152 = 'R16 '; 0x00ffffffffffffff = INVALID
        0x48344258 = 'XB4H'; 0x0000000000000000 = LINEAR
        0x48344258 = 'XB4H'; 0x0100000000000001 = INTEL_X_TILED
        0x48344258 = 'XB4H'; 0x0100000000000002 = INTEL_Y_TILED
        0x48344258 = 'XB4H'; 0x0100000000000006 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS
        0x48344258 = 'XB4H'; 0x0100000000000008 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS_CC
        0x48344258 = 'XB4H'; 0x00ffffffffffffff = INVALID
        0x38385247 = 'GR88'; 0x0000000000000000 = LINEAR
        0x38385247 = 'GR88'; 0x0100000000000001 = INTEL_X_TILED
        0x38385247 = 'GR88'; 0x0100000000000002 = INTEL_Y_TILED
        0x38385247 = 'GR88'; 0x0100000000000006 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS
        0x38385247 = 'GR88'; 0x0100000000000008 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS_CC
        0x38385247 = 'GR88'; 0x00ffffffffffffff = INVALID
        0x36314752 = 'RG16'; 0x0000000000000000 = LINEAR
        0x36314752 = 'RG16'; 0x0100000000000001 = INTEL_X_TILED
        0x36314752 = 'RG16'; 0x0100000000000002 = INTEL_Y_TILED
        0x36314752 = 'RG16'; 0x0100000000000006 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS
        0x36314752 = 'RG16'; 0x0100000000000008 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS_CC
        0x36314752 = 'RG16'; 0x00ffffffffffffff = INVALID
        0x32335247 = 'GR32'; 0x0000000000000000 = LINEAR
        0x32335247 = 'GR32'; 0x0100000000000001 = INTEL_X_TILED
        0x32335247 = 'GR32'; 0x0100000000000002 = INTEL_Y_TILED
        0x32335247 = 'GR32'; 0x0100000000000006 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS
        0x32335247 = 'GR32'; 0x0100000000000008 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS_CC
        0x32335247 = 'GR32'; 0x00ffffffffffffff = INVALID
        0x32315241 = 'AR12'; 0x0000000000000000 = LINEAR
        0x32315241 = 'AR12'; 0x0100000000000001 = INTEL_X_TILED
        0x32315241 = 'AR12'; 0x0100000000000002 = INTEL_Y_TILED
        0x32315241 = 'AR12'; 0x0100000000000006 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS
        0x32315241 = 'AR12'; 0x0100000000000008 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS_CC
        0x32315241 = 'AR12'; 0x00ffffffffffffff = INVALID
    tranche
        target device: 0xE201 (/dev/dri/card1 or /dev/dri/renderD128)
        flags: none
        formats (fourcc) and modifiers (names):
        0x34325241 = 'AR24'; 0x0000000000000000 = LINEAR
        0x34325241 = 'AR24'; 0x0100000000000001 = INTEL_X_TILED
        0x34325241 = 'AR24'; 0x0100000000000002 = INTEL_Y_TILED
        0x34325241 = 'AR24'; 0x0100000000000006 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS
        0x34325241 = 'AR24'; 0x0100000000000008 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS_CC
        0x34325241 = 'AR24'; 0x00ffffffffffffff = INVALID
        0x34324241 = 'AB24'; 0x0000000000000000 = LINEAR
        0x34324241 = 'AB24'; 0x0100000000000001 = INTEL_X_TILED
        0x34324241 = 'AB24'; 0x0100000000000002 = INTEL_Y_TILED
        0x34324241 = 'AB24'; 0x0100000000000006 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS
        0x34324241 = 'AB24'; 0x0100000000000008 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS_CC
        0x34324241 = 'AB24'; 0x00ffffffffffffff = INVALID
        0x34324258 = 'XB24'; 0x0000000000000000 = LINEAR
        0x34324258 = 'XB24'; 0x0100000000000001 = INTEL_X_TILED
        0x34324258 = 'XB24'; 0x0100000000000002 = INTEL_Y_TILED
        0x34324258 = 'XB24'; 0x0100000000000006 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS
        0x34324258 = 'XB24'; 0x0100000000000008 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS_CC
        0x34324258 = 'XB24'; 0x00ffffffffffffff = INVALID
        0x34325258 = 'XR24'; 0x0000000000000000 = LINEAR
        0x34325258 = 'XR24'; 0x0100000000000001 = INTEL_X_TILED
        0x34325258 = 'XR24'; 0x0100000000000002 = INTEL_Y_TILED
        0x34325258 = 'XR24'; 0x0100000000000006 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS
        0x34325258 = 'XR24'; 0x0100000000000008 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS_CC
        0x34325258 = 'XR24'; 0x00ffffffffffffff = INVALID
    tranche
        target device: 0xE201 (/dev/dri/card1 or /dev/dri/renderD128)
        flags: none
        formats (fourcc) and modifiers (names):
        0x30335241 = 'AR30'; 0x0000000000000000 = LINEAR
        0x30335241 = 'AR30'; 0x0100000000000001 = INTEL_X_TILED
        0x30335241 = 'AR30'; 0x0100000000000002 = INTEL_Y_TILED
        0x30335241 = 'AR30'; 0x0100000000000006 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS
        0x30335241 = 'AR30'; 0x0100000000000008 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS_CC
        0x30335241 = 'AR30'; 0x00ffffffffffffff = INVALID
        0x30335258 = 'XR30'; 0x0000000000000000 = LINEAR
        0x30335258 = 'XR30'; 0x0100000000000001 = INTEL_X_TILED
        0x30335258 = 'XR30'; 0x0100000000000002 = INTEL_Y_TILED
        0x30335258 = 'XR30'; 0x0100000000000006 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS
        0x30335258 = 'XR30'; 0x0100000000000008 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS_CC
        0x30335258 = 'XR30'; 0x00ffffffffffffff = INVALID
        0x30334241 = 'AB30'; 0x0000000000000000 = LINEAR
        0x30334241 = 'AB30'; 0x0100000000000001 = INTEL_X_TILED
        0x30334241 = 'AB30'; 0x0100000000000002 = INTEL_Y_TILED
        0x30334241 = 'AB30'; 0x0100000000000006 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS
        0x30334241 = 'AB30'; 0x0100000000000008 = INTEL_Y_TILED_GEN12_RC_CCS_CC
        0x30334241 = 'AB30'; 0x00ffffffffffffff = INVALID
interface: 'wp_linux_drm_syncobj_manager_v1',            version:  1, name: 59
interface: 'kde_output_device_v2',                       version:  8, name: 60
interface: 'wl_output',                                  version:  4, name: 61
    name: eDP-1
    x: 3000, y: 840, scale: 1,
    physical_width: 309 mm, physical_height: 174 mm,
    subpixel_orientation: unknown, output_transform: normal,
    mode:
        width: 1920 px, height: 1080 px, refresh: 60.049 Hz,
        flags: current
interface: 'org_kde_kwin_blur_manager',                  version:  1, name: 62
interface: 'org_kde_kwin_contrast_manager',              version:  2, name: 63
interface: 'org_kde_kwin_slide_manager',                 version:  1, name: 64
interface: 'kde_output_device_v2',                       version:  8, name: 65
interface: 'wl_output',                                  version:  4, name: 66
    name: HDMI-A-1
    x: 1080, y: 420, scale: 1,
    physical_width: 477 mm, physical_height: 268 mm,
    subpixel_orientation: unknown, output_transform: normal,
    mode:
        width: 1920 px, height: 1080 px, refresh: 60.000 Hz,
        flags: current
interface: 'kde_output_device_v2',                       version:  8, name: 67
interface: 'wl_output',                                  version:  4, name: 68
    name: DP-1
    x: 0, y: 0, scale: 1,
    physical_width: 477 mm, physical_height: 268 mm,
    subpixel_orientation: unknown, output_transform: 90°,
    mode:
        width: 1920 px, height: 1080 px, refresh: 60.000 Hz,
        flags: current


This might not be the answer, but there was a request to add sticky edges
in KDE KWin in 2020, which was
implemented in 2024 in this
commit.
This subsequent
request
to disable it, says you can do so in System Settings > Mouse & Touchpad >
Screen Edges.
KWin for X11 is frozen except for bug fixes, so will not see this feature
added.

Dang it is in there, I glanced past it before… it’s a setting called “Edge barrier” with a pixel value (not a checkbox), setting it to 0 deactivates the maddening feature. Thanks!

under Fedory 41 go to System Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad -> Screen Edges->Edge barrier 100px to 0. It will then become none.
Same way you can uncheck Corner barrier
Please rank if worked.
